# Android - How to print to screen using TextView

Tags: java, arraylist, textview

just wanted to know an easy way to print to the screen. I have an activity file, and an xml, but the XML is unused. I want to be able to click a button, then display the text. I made an attempt at it, but im unsure if it is right.

```
public class ViewRemainingFixtures extends ActionBarActivity {

    //  View Remaining Fixtures
    public void ViewFixtures(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> teamsOrPlayers, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> fixtures, Integer fixturesPlayedToDate) {
        TextView display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ViewRemainingFixturesButton);
        String message = "League is complete";

        if(fixturesPlayedToDate != fixtures.get(0).size()) {

            for(int i = fixturesPlayedToDate; i < fixtures.get(0).size(); i++) {
                int homeTeam = Integer.parseInt(fixtures.get(1).get(i));
                int awayTeam = Integer.parseInt(fixtures.get(2).get(i));
                String homeTeamStr = teamsOrPlayers.get(1).get(homeTeam - 1);
                String awayTeamStr = teamsOrPlayers.get(1).get(awayTeam - 1);

                display.setText(homeTeamStr);
                display.setText(awayTeamStr);
            }
        } else {
            display.setText(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened? Errors, unexpected output, anything

Comment: Well, my app wont appear in the emulator for some reason, another whole problem, but I know that, that way of printing seems to be wrong. However if its not, have you any idea what to put in my OnCreate()?